# Skip page timer with tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, timer, tampermonkey, skip

My knowledge is limited, so I'm just praying y'all will enlighten me who knows bare minimum of JS. I want to bypass a timer that makes it unable to go to the next page (I need 35s every single time and that's a lot considering some lessons have over 200 slides). How do I write a script for tampermonkey to make it show the link to the next page instantly?

```html
    // Obsługa przycisku Dalej
    function goNext(vIsExam) {

        // Przycisk nieaktywny - blokada przejścia
        if (document.getElementById("pNext").rel != 'enabled') return false;

        if (vIsExam==1) {

            
        } else {
            location.href='../sql/MemSql.php?pRun=MemCourseGoNext&pCourseResultId=262261&pCourseLessonId=227436';
        }

    } // function

    // Aktywacja przycisku Dalej
    function waitNextLesson(vTimeLeft, vTimer) {

        setCookie('cLessonTime',vTimeLeft);

        if (vTimeLeft > 0) {
            document.getElementById('pNext').rel = 'disabled';
            document.getElementById('pNextDiv').className = 'CourseInactive';
            if (vTimer == 0) {
                document.getElementById('pNextIcon').className = 'FontAwesome';
                document.getElementById('pNextIcon').innerHTML = vTimeLeft;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('pNextIcon').className = 'FontAwesome';
                document.getElementById('pNextIcon').className = 'FontAwesome FontAwesomeArrowRight';
            }
            document.getElementById('pNextName').innerHTML = 'CZEKAJ';
            vTimeLeft = vTimeLeft - 1;
            setTimeout("waitNextLesson("+vTimeLeft+","+vTimer+")",1000);
        } else {
            document.getElementById('pNext').rel = 'enabled';
            document.getElementById('pNextDiv').className = '';
            document.getElementById('pNextIcon').className = 'FontAwesome FontAwesomeArrowRight';
            document.getElementById('pNextIcon').innerHTML = '';
            document.getElementById('pNextName').innerHTML = 'NASTĘPNY SLAJD';
            if (document.getElementById('iLessonAutoPlay').checked == true) document.getElementById('pNext').click();
        }

    } // function

    // Obsługa LessonAutoPlay
    function jLessonAutoPlay(e) {
        setCookie('LessonAutoPlay', document.getElementById('iLessonAutoPlay').checked);
        jStopPropagation(e);
    } // function
    //if (getCookie('LessonAutoPlay') == 'true') document.getElementById('iLessonAutoPlay').checked = true;

    // Obsługa skrótów klawiaturowych (strzałka [<] i [>])
    $("body").keyup(function(oEvent){

        // Sprawdzenie czy można obsługiwać skróty
        if (document.getElementById('DIALOG').style.display == 'none' && document.getElementById('LOADER').style.display == 'none') {
            // Klawisz [<]
            if (oEvent.keyCode == 37) {
                document.getElementById("pPrev").click();
            }
            // Klawisz [>]
            if (oEvent.keyCode == 39) {
                if (document.getElementById("pNext").rel == 'enabled') {
                    document.getElementById("pNext").click();
                }
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: We don't know how does the website's code looks like so it's hard or even impossible to guess how to do this

Comment: Your question is not clear. Whose code is above? How does the website timer work - can you post the JavaScript for it? What is the HTML that is involved?